# Simple webapplication on weblogic 10g getting JSP error

Tags: jsp, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am developing a simple web application (or actually following the [Java EE 5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbnp.html)) on WebLogic 10g.

The application is pretty simple except for the fact that it was intended for GlassFish. It consists of a simple JSP page (take a look at the link above) which connects to an EJB. However, I am getting the following error and I am not able to resolve the proper libraries for the project.

> weblogic.application.WrappedDeploymentException: Absent Code attribute
>   in method that is not native or abstract in class file
>   javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport

My Maven pom file contains the following dependencies except client jar for these EJB

```xml
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are actually deploying those artifacts, which is the main problem.

There are several problems in total though:

1. As said, they shouldn't be deployed, as WebLogic 10g already implements them. In Maven you should use the provided scope (`<scope>provided</scope>`)
2. The `javaee-api` artifact is stripped of all code. You can't deploy this even if WebLogic didn't implemented that API. This is why the exception you're getting says that there is no code available in the given class.
3. The two first dependencies overlap with the last one. Java EE already contains Servlet and JSP.
4. WebLogic 10g is a Java EE 5 implementation, but you have a Java EE 6 API as a dependency, which is a completely different version.

Comment: Ah, yea. What I haven't realized that wrong version of j2ee :-) So thanks for correcting my blindness.